# Can I add a property on a directive I created afterwards the page is loaded based on IF condition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The directive is a attribute (A) one.
HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" my-amount-field amount-min="5" amount-max="120" shouldBeingChecked="{{crCtrl.form.canCashM}}" name="myLimit" id="myLimit" ng-model="crCtrl.form.limits.cash.val" ng-blur="crCtrl.form.limits.cash.errFn(cardRules)" tabindex="8" />
```

For this directive I have another attribute which is "allow-zero", but I'd like to put that attribute only IF a specific checkbox is thicked.
I was wondering if I can bind that attribute to the directive "my-amount-field" when the page obviously is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `allow-zero` it's a boolean property, if that's the case you should add the property with a boolean condition I think .. like `allow-zero="{{shouldZeroBeAllowedCondition}}"`

Comment: No, the directive checks if that attribute exist or not.

Comment: Well, you can try duplicating your inputs, one of them with the property and the otherone without it. Then add ng-if to both using the condition you want to met (of course in one of them you will need to negate the condition).

Comment: My advice would be to change the allow-zero attribute to be a boolean, it can be optional as well, but if you are just checking that it exists or not, then it's a boolean attribute to me.

Comment: OK, but my question is different.
I wanted to know if whether possible or not bind attribute to the directive afterwards to a loaded page.